# Finding optimal kernel parameters

Tags: optimization, svm, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

I want to perform multiple kernel learning on my dataset and apply each (rbf) kernel to a different subset of features to then combine them. I do not want to have the same kernel with a range of parameters (as suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/91009/284787)) but rather find the optimal parameters for each component kernel first before combining them, and then optimise the weights (as suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/67835/284787)).

I am wondering **what metric should I be using to optimise each kernel?** Would maximising the margin between the negative and positive class be appropriate? Or minimising the ratio between the radius of Minimum Enclosing Ball (MEB) and the margin?

---

UPDATE: I have come up with my own solution (accepted answer), but any feedback/comments would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am going to post my own solution to the problem, any feedback on this will be appreciated!*

I used as metric of similarity the **alignment between the kernel and the ideal kernel** (in which I have a value of 1 for samples with the same label and of -1 for samples with different labels). This is a number between 0 and 1, the higher the better.

To find the optimal value of gamma for the rbf kernel, I apply nested CV:

1. I take out a validation fold (20%) which will not be used to find the optimal $\gamma$
2. Within the train folds, I create an internal K-fold split in the dataset
   3. In the internal train fold, I search over a range of values of $\gamma$ and see which one gives me the best alignment with the ideal kernel for the internal train set
   $$
   score_{train}(\gamma) = alignment(K_{internal-train}, K_{ideal-internal-train})
   $$
   4. I take the $\gamma$ for which $score_{train}(\gamma)$ is maximal and evaluate the performance on the internal test set:
   $$
   score_{test}(\gamma) = alignment(K_{internal-test}, K_{ideal-internal-test})
   $$
   5. Repeat steps 2-4 K-fold
3. Pick the value of $\gamma$ for which $score_{test}(\gamma)$ is max and use it to compute the kernel for the dataset for the MKL and validate on the external validation set.

I repeat this procedure 5-fold to get a performance estimate of my classifier.

---

**UPDATE**

It turns out that finding the ideal kernel might overfit the data + the kernel that is the closest to the ideal kernel might not have any information to add when combined with other kernels - i.e. kernels that are weaker on their own can be much more useful when combined.

Instead of using an rbf kernel, I approximated it by using a number of homogeneous polynomial kernels (see [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316991005_Learning_Dot_Product_Polynomials_for_multiclass_problems)), which I combined without selecting. Therefore, **for each of my dataset I had D polynomial kernels with grades 1 to D** and this seems to yield really good results with my data.

Comment: what if the target values are continuous instead of binary {-1, 1} ? Did you have to binarize the output values before calculating the kernel alignment? If so, how did that affect the performance?